# How to pass JSON data to code behind method (not to Webmethod)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, c#-4.0

I have JSON data which I need to pass to code behind and bind to obout grid. I know we can pass data using `<WebMethod>`. But in Webmethod I cannot bind the data to obout grid and any grid. because it is static webmethod.

So Now I trying to call code behind method from javascript and pass the data as parameter to method. How can we do that?

```
 users = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < usersInfo.length; i++) {
          user = {
                   UserName : usersInfo[i].UserName,
                   Email : usersInfo[i].Email,
                   Status : status
          };

          users.push(user);
    }
    var results = "";
    $('#lblError').val('');
    if (users.length > 0) {
        //Pass the `users` data to ShowResults code behind method.
     }
```

### code behind

```
public void ShowResults(List<UsersInfo> users)
{
       oboutGrid.DataSource = users;
       oboutGrid.DataBind();
}

public partial class UsersInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }        
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to pass JSON object to code-behind and from code-behind bind grid, why can't do that in JS directly?

Comment: @ArindamNayak ...obout grid doesn't option to bind data from JS.

Comment: Then you can use updatepanel to do all of this thing, it may not be efficient, but you can give a try!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this, is to include a hidden field on the aspx form

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="jsonDataHolder" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
```

in this hidden field add your JSON data as a string, using JSON.stringify

```
$('#jsonDataHolder').val(JSON.stringify({ id: 1, name: "mohamed" }));
```

then when the page is normally posted back you can access the hidden field, deserilaize it and do your code

```
protected void btn_DOPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = this.jsonDataHolder.Value;
    // desrialize json, do ur code
}
```